# DataTables - Horizontal Scroll Bar Partially Covers Last Row

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, datatable

I am currently using the JQuery plugin DataTables in an ASP.Net MVC application. For some reason when I try to use the DataTable's scrollX option and set it to true, the horizontal scroll bar will partially cover the last row of information. This is slightly annoying. Would anyone know how to fix this issue. I am told this is a common issue with this plugin but cannot seem to find anything related to this on the web.

Here is some example code. I will have to use some generic names due to security reasons:

**HTML**

```
<div class="panel-body" style="padding-top: 12px;" overflow-y:hidden">

        <table id="example" style="width:100%;" class="table" cellspacing="0">
            <thead style="width:100%">
                <tr role="row">
                    <th>Column#</th>
                    <th>Column#</th>
                    <th>Column#</th>
                    <th>Column#</th>
                    <th>Column#</th>
                    <th>Column#</th>
                    <th>Column#</th>
                    <th>Column#</th>
                    <th>Column#</th>
                    <th>Column#</th>
                    <th>Column#</th>
                    <th>Column#</th>
                    <th>Column#</th>
                    <th>Column#</th>
                    <th>Column#</th>
                    <th>Column#</th>
                    <th>Column#</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
<script>
    var table1 = $('#example').DataTable({
         "scrollX": true, 
         dom: "Bfrtip", 
         "buttons": [], 
         "processing": true, 
         "serverSide": true, "ajax": {"url": "/Home/MyAction", 
                  "type": "POST", 
                  "data": function (d) { modD(d);}}
    });
</script>
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: "*when I try to use the DataTable's scrollX option and set it to true, the horizontal scroll bar will partially cover the last row of information (...) I am told this is a common issue with this plugin*", this do not sound right at all. Please setup a fiddle that reproduce the problem.  Here is a starting point -> **http://jsfiddle.net/0f9Ljfjr/940/**

Comment: @davidkonrad Certainly, I'll try to get that set up to recreate the issue.

Comment: @davidkonrad I could not reproduce the issue on jsfiddle, I did however fix the issue.  All I needed to do was add the BootStrap table-responsive to the table's "class" attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I actually figured out what the issue was, or at least found a solution to my particular issue. Notice in my initial post that I was using just the Bootstrap "table" class, once I added "table-responsive" as well that seemed to fix the issue. Don't exactly know why that fixed it but hey no complaints here. Hope this helps someone else experiencing the same issue.

Here is the code with the edit:

```
<div class="panel-body" style="padding-top: 12px;" overflow-y:hidden">

    <table id="example" style="width:100%;" class="table table-responsive" cellspacing="0">
        <thead style="width:100%">
            <tr role="row">
                <th>Column#</th>
                <th>Column#</th>
                <th>Column#</th>
                <th>Column#</th>
                <th>Column#</th>
                <th>Column#</th>
                <th>Column#</th>
                <th>Column#</th>
                <th>Column#</th>
                <th>Column#</th>
                <th>Column#</th>
                <th>Column#</th>
                <th>Column#</th>
                <th>Column#</th>
                <th>Column#</th>
                <th>Column#</th>
                <th>Column#</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<script>
     var table1 = $('#example').DataTable({
         "scrollX": true, 
         dom: "Bfrtip", 
         "buttons": [], 
         "processing": true, 
         "serverSide": true, 
         "ajax": {"url": "/Home/MyAction", 
             "type": "POST", 
             "data": function (d) { modD(d);}}
     });
</script>
```